# Do I need a clear path to the target, or just my familiar, when delivering spells with Find Familiar?

Tags: dnd-5e, familiars, spellcasting, targeting, line-of-effect

Here's the setup:

- My familiar is adjacent to the creature I want to target with my touch spell, and is within 100' of me.
- Both the target and my familiar are around a corner, and I do not have a clear path to them.
- I cast the touch spell on my turn, and my familiar uses its reaction to deliver the spell.

My familiar has a clear path to the target, but I don't. I think that's fine, and it all works. Does this function as I described?

Comment: A related question that might answer parts of yours: "[Does a touch-range spell cast using Find Familiar have to have line of sight from the caster?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/125996)"

Comment: @Someone_Evil Thanks for the suggestion. Just FYI, in case you're interested in the perspective of a new user, if you immediately shut the thread down before giving ~24 hours to fix the error, it can come across as a little harsh. I realize you're just trying to maintain standards, which I appreciate, but I think giving people a little time to react can be useful. Either way, I've edited it, so hopefully you can open it again and answer the question properly. The link you provided mentions line of sight, but basically answers the question. I think my setup is more clear, and doesn't use LoS.

Comment: @Ira We know about the harshness of it (it has been much discussed on the network), but we prefer to close quickly to prevent malplaced answers coming in. Our capacity to close and reopen quickly is often much higher than a single users ability to edit their question, so this is to prevent unclear (or otherwise problematic) question lying around in the open, or answers which aren't for the intended, productive question to come in.

Comment: @Someone I think the difference in the *question* is line of sight vs line of effect (clear path). Though the answer to the line of sight question also addresses the line of effect (clear path) aspect

Comment: @Someone_Evil Thanks for the nice reply. I understand. I guess perhaps the tone can just be a little rough when you come back to your thread and at the top it says "CLOSED! Bad job!"  I think it can be a turn-off for new users. Maybe it's just a messaging thing, and you can make it a more friendly note. "Thanks for posting a question, but because we want to ensure blah blah... and we can open it up again really quickly once you correct this. Thank you!"

Comment: Either way, re: dupe, yes that thread answers the question, but "line of sight" is really confusing, and should use "clear path to target" instead, since that's the language in the rulebook, and people will search for that. And it really buries the lede. But for personal reasons, I don't care any more because my question is answered. :)

Answer (score 6):

### You do not need a clear path to the target

The familiar delivers the spell as if it had cast the spell.

> When you Cast a Spell with a range of touch, your familiar can deliver
>   the spell as if it had cast the spell. *PHB 240*

Since your familiar is casting the spell, your character does not need a clear path to the target.

Your familiar will need a clear path to the target and your character will need to be within 100 feet of your familiar.

> Your familiar must be within 100 feet of you, and it must use its
>   reaction to deliver the spell when you cast it. If the spell requires
>   an attack roll, you use your attack modifier for the roll. *PHB 240*